# GLS failed with status 20 －Android Get User Location

Tags: android, gps, location

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
List <Address> myLocation = null;
try {
myLocation = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The log is below:

```
LocationMasfClient: reverseGeocode(): GLS failed with status 20
```

I can not find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

See [Help! Geocoding fails: forwardGeocode(): GLS failed with status 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273050/help-geocoding-fails-forwardgeocode-gls-failed-with-status-20) if u use API v8

Often GLS works on the second try in my app...

```
try {
              //Place geocoder here
} catch (IOException e) {
              //Try again
              Thread.sleep(1500);
              Log.e(this.toString(), "Slept for a while (1500 ms). Let's try reverse geocoding again...");
              //Place geocoder here again
              Log.d(this.toString(), "Success! It's always good to take a nap...");
}
```