# Help! Geocoding fails: forwardGeocode(): GLS failed with status 20

Tags: android, geocoding

After I upgraded to Android SDK 8 I started seeing geocoding failures in the emulator. However, everything was fine on a device.

Now my app fails to gecode on 1.5 and 1.6 devices as well as in the emulator. Has anyone been able to fix this? I can't test on a 2.2 device. Perhaps it works OK there.

Is anyone else suffering from this and have they fixed it?

Many thanks,

pawpaw17

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding doesnt work on the emulator on API 8, I dont know why, but it just doesnt, run in on a API7 emulator, if it works there it should work on a real 2.2 device.

I had this exact same problem not so long ago, runs fine on the device (nexus one & G2), does nothing on the emulator.