# reverse geocoding not working : Google paltform : 2.2 , Api :8

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting null pointer exception when I am trying to get lat/long from address using reverse geocoding in Android.... can you pleas elet me know is there any other way??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help! Geocoding fails: forwardGeocode(): GLS failed with status 20](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273050/help-geocoding-fails-forwardgeocode-gls-failed-with-status-20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app must not be recieving Location updates..

Your code must be calling getLattitude or getLongitude method on location object..

Unless You recieve a location update .. This will always cause null pointer exception

For better Result Test Your Application on a real device .
 If Using Simulator Check it is GPS Enabled.

Check Your manifest file for Location permission.

implement location listener perfectly.

If you need code for this i will post that too . if you can do its good.

Comment: thanks.. Its actually giving "IoException" and since later I am accessing null geopoint its crashing..                               code snippet :   Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in the emulator. It works OK on real devices apparently. See

[link text](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816)